# AndroidStudio doesn't create R.java?

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I'm using `Android Studio v0.2.6` and I don't know why, but there is no `R.java` file created in my project. Therefore the autocomplete-thing tries to import `android.R` and everything is messed up. Is there any way to force AS to reset the project properties and try to recreate the `R.java`? Rebuilding doesn't work, I tried a lot that was suggested in other questions.

Comment: Do you have any error on your resources file? Start by fixing this!

Comment: First remove the `android.R` from everywhere. Then try to Clean the project and see if any error pops-up. Then go to your XML files (or paste them here so we can see too) and look for errors there (e.g. stupid errors like unclosed string resources tages, or ones closed with  inappropriate tag etc.).

Comment: I couldnt find any errors in my resource files, could you tell me how to "clean" my project?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue - make sure your src, gen and libs folders are set as source folder in the Project Structure dialog.  ( Open Project Structure -> Modules -> YourApp -> Sources.  Ctrl click src and gen and click Sources above )

Comment: I dont know what happened, but it seems fixed. But I still dont have a gen folder?