# Android Studio Create Project Trouble

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have a problem when i create new project on Android Studio. i create new project and set    minimum sdk   and target sdk version options. i m sure ,i did not anything wrong. Then project created but  java directory not exist in project tree.that's the problem.
[image]
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18575460/1980819

You need to specify your source folders in the project tree (they'll go blue after, like below):

[image]